# What are flip-flops&latches and transmission&switch gates in Verilog?

Tags: verilog

I've looked everywhere to figure out what flip-flops and latches are. Could you give me a brief description of them in the simplest possible way (as if to a child)?

Also, could you tell me the functionalities, input and output of transmission primitives (buf, bufif0, bufif1, notif0, notif1) and switch primitives (pmos, rpmos, nmos, rnmos, cmos, rcmos, tranif1, tranif0, rtranif1, rtranif0, tran, rtran, pullup, pulldown)?

It is a lot of stuff I am requesting, so if you have a URL with comprehensive description of the given primitives, and any other ones with other introductory level information on Verilog, I would be very grateful. (NOT http://www.asic-world.com because that is precisely where I'm learning this from and I don't understand them)

PS: I'd like to be familiar with more primitives to prepare for my exam.

Comment: Try googeling "verilog 101" - maybe electronics.SO might be a valid place to ask as well. We normally focus on problems with code here - and one question. Giving and introductionary course to verilog is kindof off topic - my guess. With google you get links like this https://www.cs.upc.edu/~jordicf/Teaching/secretsofhardware/VerilogIntroduction_Nyasulu.pdf which might explain stuff in depth and other wording then you current learning resource.

Comment: verilog is a language to describe behavior of hardware. Th terms you listed are not related specifically to verilog and are hardware concepts. So, you need to get some knowledge of electronics before attempting modeling them.

Comment: OP, there are other Stacks: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/21887/difference-between-latch-and-flip-flop

Comment: For what it's worth: the MOS primitives (`pmos`, `cmos`, `tranif`, etc) are almost never used. They might have applications in some ASIC workflows, but they cannot be synthesized in FPGAs/CPLDs, and may not be supported by some simulators.

Answer (score -1):

> Could you give me a brief description of them in the simplest possible way (as if to a child)?

Once upon a time a wise genie named Lindley invented a magical box called a Flip-Flop. Whenever the enchanted Clock strikes a chime, if a peasant farmer Mr. D. is feeling high, his neighbor Mrs. Q will see this and suddenly do a "flip", landing upon the rail. And there she stays until the next time the clock chimes.

But instead, if Mr. D. is feeling low when the enchanted clock chimes, Mrs. Q will "flop", quite dejectedly, ending up flat on the ground.

And so this continues on forever as long as the enchanted clock continues to chime, with Q flipping and flopping as to however D feels. But only each time the clock chimes, much to the bemusement of the genie. If the clock were to stop, Q will freeze right where she is, and no matter what is happening to D, there she will stay frozen.

This may seem an singularly odd amusement, but it happens that with enough enchanted boxes and flipping peasants, a wise fellow named Turing is said to be able to compute most nearly anything.

Now a latch is something, not quite different, but also very much not quite the same. It involves some different peasants and in lieu of the magical clock, another peasant simply tells the others when to freeze. For this reason it is not as interesting as the famous flip-flop of Antioch.

> if you have a URL with comprehensive description of the given primitives

Please see the following freely download-able reference. This contains comprehensive and authoritative descriptions of all of the primitives you request.

[IEEE 1800 System Verilog-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf)